# MySQL Trigger - AFTER CREATE ON not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, schema

When I try to create a trigger which insert something in the table `questiontypes` after the creation of a table in USER1 schema I get this error from MySQL (executing it on phpmyadmin) : `Sorry an unexpected error happened!`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_table_trigger
AFTER CREATE ON USER1.SCHEMA
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USER1.questiontypes VALUES('text');
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: MySQL only supports INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE triggers as far as I know.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks for the answer, I've just spent 1hour on this trying to find a solution haha

Comment: @Uueerdo Have you got any links to documentation to support it? If so could you post it as an answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to find documentation on the non-existence of something; but the absence of any mention of DDL triggers from MYSQL's rather detailed documentation is a big indicator.

Also, the official documentation on CREATE TRIGGER only show INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE as event types. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

The nearest I could find any official mention was from an unassigned MySql "worklog" entry [here](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2418), documenting a request for the feature.